# Filter Query Results - multiple criteria Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have been designing a database system for where I work to help some of our advisers select appropriate products quickly over the phone.

I have all the tables setup with all the information ( as provided by a colleague).

I have run into an issue as there is a magnitude of criteria that could possibly be applied. I have only ever done a single criteria. What would be the best method to filter down the list of products.

Below is a screenshot of our User interface with the number of the criteria.

[image]

The product name list is populated upon the user selecting the brand name. The option buttons then allow the user to filter down the list as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in an Access database app at work. The way I do it is to have a bunch of criteria at the top of my form, like you do on the left side of your image, to have a <kbd>Find</kbd> button after all the criteria, and then to have a datasheet subform to show all the found matches given the criteria.

The subform would be bound to a data source which would be a SQL query like the following:

```
select *
from tbl_products
where brand_name = [Forms]![MyForm]![BrandName]
and option_1 = [Forms]![MyForm]![Option1]
and option_2 = [Forms]![MyForm]![Option2]
...
```

And you would need a little VBA event handler to handle the click event on the <kbd>Find</kbd> button to just refresh the subform. That would automatically re-run the above query and show all matching products.

A little complication though: you would need to decide what it means to leave one of the options unchecked. Does it mean 'no, I don't want this option', or does it mean 'I don't know what the choice is for this option'? If the latter, I would probably use a group of three radio buttons ('Yes', 'No', 'Don't know') instead of a checkbox, for clarity. Sure, it's a little more complicated for you the form developer, but it's more clear for the user.

Comment: Fantastic thank you, I have since been asked to replace these with Dropdown Comboboxes instead. Hopefully this should reduce the amount of options and make it a little easier.

Comment: @user1857233 - yeah, that should help.

Comment: Hi, I have done as you suggested and it works fantastically other than when I try to incorporate the brand. When ever i try to run the query using the brand name the rowsource is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: `Me.cboProduct.RowSource = "SELECT ProductName FROM Product_Att_Qry WHERE Brand = cboBrand.Value BoilerType = cboType.Value AND Fuel = cboFuel.Value and Condensing = cboCondense.Value ORDER BY ProductName;"`

Comment: @user1857233 - you seem to be missing an `and` keyword in your rowsource query. `... where Brand = cboBrand.Value and BoilerType = ...`. As to the brand name problem, I will edit my answer a little--check if that works.

Comment: Ah sorry that was a mistake while i was typing it out. My apologies. For instance, if i search for Brand1, where boiler type is R Fuel is Oil, and Condesning is Yes... The rowsource remains blank. However when I remove the Brand it works perfectly fine just the list includes the two testing brands. 

However when i wrote this as an SQL query in access it worked perfectly fine. I'm a little baffled.

Comment: @user1857233 - I am composing a new query for you to try, but can you clarify: all the parameters you are filtering by in the `where` clause are strings (i.e., `varchars`)? If so they must be wrapped in single quotes in the query.

Comment: All the parameters are indeed strings.